# SQL Server Decenteralized table performance issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having difficulties with optimizing a query. Table has 42 columns and 1.7 million records. As I mentioned on the subject, the table is a decentralized one. We have a few int type columns and the rest of them are varchar text fields.
On a normal work day this table has 10k inserts and around 250k updates daily. As our statistics shows, table answers 550k select requests in a work day.
Since this table has a lot of business rules related to the application layer, there are 12 different conditions where conditions exist.
Out of 42 columns, we are selecting 34 of them all the time. All columns are sortable and searchable and that's why we are using dynamic sql to achieve that. Like;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[jo_JobOrder_PerfIndex_Test] 
            @companyID int,--255
            @state int,--null
            @status int,
            @skip int,
            @take int,
            @filterDateType int,
            @technicianID int,
            @filterModelID int,
            @filterCustomerID int,
            @pastTenDate datetime,
            @CategoryID int,
            @TeamID int,
            @CustomSearchParam nvarchar(100),
            @FilterStartDate datetime,
            @FilterEndDate datetime,
            @AssociatedCustomerFilter int,
            @OrderByColumn varchar(50),
            @OrderByDirection nvarchar(50),
            @ForceStrictlyCompany int,
            @deviceType nvarchar(50)
AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SET @Sql=';WITH TempResult AS(Select JobOrder_PerfTable.JobOrderID,ReferenceID,Customer,SerialNo,DeviceName,DeviceTypeName,DeviceBrand,StateID,Staff,JobOrder_PerfTable.GsmNo,StartDate,EndDate,ActualStartDate,ActualEndDate,RelatedFirm,AppointmentDate,ServiceType,CompanyName,Cost,1 as [PassedTime],JobOrder_PerfTable.Address,Description,
Province,District,CurrentFullFilled,DealerTrackCode,CargoDetails,NotifiedFault,State,TagName,JobOrder_PerfTable.SortID,JobOrder_PerfTable.CompanyID,JobOrder_PerfTable.PhoneNumber,JobOrder_PerfTable.Importance,
JobOrder_PerfTable.Status,null as CategoryID,JobOrder_PerfTable.RepeatCount,JobOrder_PerfTable.Attributes,JobOrder_PerfTable.DeliveryShipmentNo,JobOrder_PerfTable.CreatedBy,
0 as [DeviceChange],
0 as [DeviceReturn],
0 as [SNORepeat]
 from JobOrder_PerfTable
 WITH(NOLOCK)
inner join Companies On Companies.CompanyID=JobOrder_PerfTable.CompanyID
WHERE  ((@state is null or JobOrder_PerfTable.StateID=@state) OR @state=-2 AND JobOrder_PerfTable.JobOrderID IN ( select jobOrderID from attendedStaffStatistics where StaffID=@technicianID AND CONVERT(date,AttendedStaffStatistics.InsertDate, 105)=CONVERT(date, getdate(), 105) ))
            AND ((@status = -1 AND JobOrder_PerfTable.Status IN(0,1,10,11,4)) OR (@status=1 AND JobOrder_PerfTable.Status IN(1,4,10,11)) OR
             (@status=2 AND JobOrder_PerfTable.Status IN (0))) AND (@CategoryID is null or JobOrder_PerfTable.CategoryID=@CategoryID)
             AND (@AssociatedCustomerFilter is null or Joborder_PerfTable.CustomerID IN (Select CustomerID from Customers where RelatedFirmID IN (select CustomerID from StaffAssignedToCustomer where StaffID=@AssociatedCustomerFilter) UNION select CustomerID from StaffAssignedToCustomer where StaffID=@AssociatedCustomerFilter))
             AND ((@ForceStrictlyCompany>0 AND JobOrder_PerfTable.CompanyID=@ForceStrictlyCompany) OR (@ForceStrictlyCompany is null AND (JobOrder_PerfTable.CompanyID=@companyID OR Companies.SubCompanyOf=@companyID)))
                 '+ ( CASE WHEN @CustomSearchParam='' THEN '' ELSE (Select dbo.[perf_likeBuilder](@CustomSearchParam)) END)+'
             AND (@technicianID is null or JobOrder_PerfTable.JobOrderID IN (Select AttendedStaff.JobOrderID from AttendedStaff Where AttendedStaff.StaffID=@technicianID))
             AND (@pastTenDate is null or  JobOrder_PerfTable.StartDate<@pastTenDate)
             AND (@filterModelID is null or JobOrder_PerfTable.DeviceModelID=@filterModelID)
             AND (@filterCustomerID is null or JobOrder_PerfTable.CustomerID=@filterCustomerID)
             AND (@deviceType is null or JobOrder_PerfTable.DeviceTypeName=@deviceType)
             AND ((@filterDateType=1 AND (@FilterStartDate is null or convert(datetime, JobOrder_PerfTable.StartDate, 20) between @FilterStartDate and @FilterEndDate)) OR (@filterDateType=2 AND (@FilterStartDate is null or convert(datetime, JobOrder_PerfTable.EndDate, 20) between @FilterStartDate and @FilterEndDate)))
             ), TotalCount AS (Select COUNT(*) as TotalCount from TempResult) 
             
             Select * from TempResult, TotalCount 
          order by '+@OrderByColumn+' '+@OrderByDirection+'

            OFFSET     @skip ROWS      
FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY 
OPTION (RECOMPILE); ';


EXECUTE sp_executesql  @sql, N'@companyID int,
            @state int,
            @status int,
            @skip int,@take int,
            @filterDateType int,
            @technicianID int,
            @filterModelID int,
            @filterCustomerID int,
            @pastTenDate datetime,
            @CategoryID int,
            @TeamID int,
            @CustomSearchParam nvarchar(100),
            @FilterStartDate datetime,
            @FilterEndDate datetime,
            @AssociatedCustomerFilter int,
            @ForceStrictlyCompany int,
            @deviceType nvarchar(50)',
            @companyID=@companyID,
            @state=@state,
            @status=@status,
            @skip=@skip,
            @take=@take,
            @filterDateType=@filterDateType,
            @technicianID=@technicianID,
            @filterModelID=@filterModelID,
            @filterCustomerID=@filterCustomerID,
            @pastTenDate=@pastTenDate,
            @CategoryID=@CategoryID,            
            @TeamID=@TeamID,
            @CustomSearchParam=@CustomSearchParam,
            @FilterStartDate=@FilterStartDate,
            @FilterEndDate=@FilterEndDate,
            @AssociatedCustomerFilter=@AssociatedCustomerFilter,
            @ForceStrictlyCompany=@ForceStrictlyCompany,
            @deviceType=@deviceType
```

**What I tried already**

- Indexed most of the columns in where clause
- Give up on dynamic stuff and converted the query as regular one(no changes)
- Thought it might be a execution plan problem and/or parameter sniffing, decorated query with OPTION(RECOMPILE)
- Since table has like crazy amount of updates, tried querying it with WITH(nolock)

**What I already know**

- Selecting all rows are bad.
- Indexing all columns  or too much index is bad (update queries)
- Key lookup's happens when index not covering all columns in select but I can't add 35 columns to an index.
- Key lookups are not necessarily a bad thing.
- Parallelism might cause slow queries since other table has bad indexes or other problems. (in this case other table has 5k rows)

[image]

When this query works it takes  3 seconds at best and takes a lot of cpu to run.  When 10 of them work at the same time, the whole system responds slowly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should really improve the layout of the dynamic sql query. That's not pleasant to read.

Comment: Is `AS(Select 42Rows) from Orders ` meant to say columns? Getting rows and columns confused is making this hard to get my head around.

Comment: 3 things that I see from the screenshot, your statistics are completly off. (2 actual of 476996 estimated) => results in a sub optimal query plan. Key lookup with a cost of +65% is probably an issue. Since you have aggregates in your plan, it might be a good idea to create a [clustered index view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87319/67402)

Comment: Your sql and execution plan have different table names. Please edit the sql to match the execution plan. Then add the table definitions, indexes, etc.

Comment: You need to start by identifying the slowest variants of your query: each set of WHERE clauses needs to be optimized separately. Use SSMS to run the slowest queries, but before you do right-click in the query window and choose Show Actual Execution Plan. Then, after the query runs, look at the execution plan. It sometimes suggests a useful index. Repeat this for each slow query variant. It's a pain in the neck, but the only good way to handle your problem.

Comment: @MatBailie copy pasted whole query. I didn't want to make your eyes bleed but you are right. you can not give an answer without the whole picture.

Comment: @MatBailie updated again.

Comment: Read the link at the end of my answer. There are too many topics to cover here, the size of the article is a reflection of the size of the hole you're in. The short answer is to NOT write one big query that satisfies all scernaios. Instead you need much more sophisticated code to write bespoke queries for your different parameters, and avoid OR conditions at all costs. You've saved development time by bunching it all in to one, but that just pushes the cost on to the server at run time. It's a brute force approach, which never scales well.

Comment: @habo that's the same link as I gave.

Comment: First of all, I will get rid of "or" conditions. And optimize query by most used where conditions. Thank you @MatBailie

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted your SQL so that it's readable.

You have the wrong number of braces in the where clause, and what I presume I a a missing `AND`. So, at present this doesn't even run, and I can't trust other errors haven't been made when copying the query here.

The first condition of the where clause, is also redundant, as the company_id is already equal due to the join predicate.

Don't use `(@param IS NULL or table.column = @param)`, it can really mess up the optimiser. Instead just check @param when building the dynamic query. If it's null, don't embed anything in the where clause.

OR conditions in general are also bad for performance.

You have `Orders.Status=@status OR Orders.State=@state`, which will essentially require two different indexes to optimise. But the optimiser has to predict which One will be best to use based on cardinality. It can't optimise Both conditions.

The usual compromise is to UNION two queries together. But that depends on your data. I also can't tell if you ever use both filters, or if at least one is always null.

Similarly no single index can satisfy all your possible permutations. Indexes aren't magical, they're just like indexes in the back of a book, they're sorted references. If you have an index on `(a, b)` and then search for `b=1`, the index is essentially useless.

So, if you want faste queries, you Must tailor your indexes to the posable search patterns.

This does indeed slow down updates. But that's the cost. Indexes and optimisation isn't magic. If you want to speed up reads, you necessarily slow down writes.

```
SET @Sql = '
  WITH
    TempResult AS
  (
    SELECT
      <42Rows>
    FROM
      orders
    INNER JOIN
      companies
        ON companies.companyID = orders.companyID
    WHERE
         (Orders.CompanyId=Companies.CompanyID OR Orders.CompanyId=Companies.SubCompanyOf)
    (
      (@status is null or Orders.Status=@status)
      OR @state is null
      OR Orders.State=@state)
    )
    AND '+@whereColumn +' '+@searchTerm+'
    ORDER BY 
      '+@OrderByColumn+' '+@OrderByDirection
        
  EXECUTE sp_executeSql @sql ...(parameters so on)
```

In short, please correct the mistakes to the sql query, and give use case and descriptions on how the parameters can and can not be set.

Also, read this; https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

There's a LOT of detail in there, but for your scenario, that's what you need to learn to understand and deal with.

Comment: `@param is null or col=@param` is fine when used with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, as here.  There will be no query plan reuse, but for the null parameters the predicate will be trimmed from the query plan.